# Does `isa` pointer carry other message about an instantiation in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I always think the `isa` pointer points to the Class of the instantiation. And the Class's `isa` pointer points to the its `metaclass`. 
But in some article about the introduction of `isa` pointer, the author wrote: every bits in `isa` pointer can carry some message about the object. This like following:

[[objc explain]: Non-pointer isa](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html)

[从 NSObject 的初始化了解 isa](http://draveness.me/isa/)

```
1   bit indexed 0 is raw isa, 1 is non-pointer isa.
1   bit has_assoc   Object has or once had an associated reference. Object with no associated references can deallocate faster.
1   bit has_cxx_dtor    Object has a C++ or ARC destructor. Objects with no destructor can deallocate faster.
30  bits    shiftcls    Class pointer's non-zero bits.
9   bits    magic   Equals 0xd2. Used by the debugger to distinguish real objects from uninitialized junk.
1   bit weakly_referenced   Object is or once was pointed to by an ARC weak variable. Objects not weakly referenced can deallocate faster.
1   bit deallocating    Object is currently deallocating.
1   bit has_sidetable_rc    Object's retain count is too large to store inline.
19  bits    extra_rc
```

But in my test, I found the low three bits were always **0**, it just like:

[image]

And I had added the associated object in `NSObject`, but the second bit (`has_assoc`) is not **1** in `isa` pointer.

So how can I understand the `isa` pointer?

Comment: Did you test on the simulator or on a real device?

Comment: How old is the reference you found?  The in-memory representation of an object can be changed any time Apple feels like it.

Comment: That post is from 2013 and contains the following: _For entertainment purposes only. These values will change in future OS versions. I think they already have changed, actually._

Comment: @Avi If you know the reason, I hope you can give an answer. If you don't know, there is no need to waste time to comment me. : )

Comment: You could check the Swift runtime source or the Foundation source, both available from Apple.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks a lot. I test on my real device, it is different. So I think the simulator's architecture is different from the real device. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an associated object to a value of `nil` is a no-op, and will not be added to the associated objects side-table. Thus, it's `isa` tag does not change.

See the following example, to show that the tag bits do work:

```
NSObject *object = [NSObject new];

NSLog(@"isa: %p ", *(void **)(__bridge void *)object);

static void *someKey = &someKey;
objc_setAssociatedObject(object, someKey, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

NSLog(@"isa: %p ", *(void **)(__bridge void *)object);
```

For me, on OSX 10.11 outputs:

```
2016-09-22 14:37:20.132 TestProj[95942:1117770] isa: 0x1dffff757a50f1 
2016-09-22 14:37:24.208 TestProj[95942:1117770] isa: 0x1dffff757a50f1
```

But if I change the value from nil to an actual pointer value:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(object, someKey, @"Hello World!", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

I get the (expected) output, which includes the tagged bits being set in the pointer:

```
2016-09-22 14:40:24.190 TestProj[96095:1121411] isa: 0x1dffff757a50f1 
2016-09-22 14:40:24.191 TestProj[96095:1121411] isa: 0x1dffff757a50f3
```

Comment: Thx a lot. But In my test, I can't get the result as your code. And if I change the value from nil to an actual pointer value, the output is same as ago. I test it in OSX 10.11, by xcode 8.0. And Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38). Could you show me your proj about this example by screenshot?

Comment: Thank you very much. I get the true result by my iPhone. And I think it's the problem of the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,there have two points that you should know.

First,in most cases,pass a `nil` value to a dictionary cause to remove the key form the dictionary.

Such as `- (void)setObject:(ObjectType)object forKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)aKey` and `void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
dic[@"name"] = @"酷酷的哀殿";
dic[@"name"] = nil;

NSLog(@"%@", dic);// it's output is `{}`.
```

Second,you should know the byte-order of your target device.

You can test it by follow code.

```
int msg      = 0x01020304;
char *buffer = (char *)&msg;
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
```

In my x86-64 device,it's output is `4 3 2 1`.

So,when I change `has_assoc`,the last but one byte will have a change.

And in pointer,it will add/minus `2`.

```
isa: 0x1dffff795ca0f1 

isa: 0x1dffff795ca0f3
```

For `isa_t`,you can use follow code to get `has_assoc`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>


int main() {



  // extra_rc must be the MSB-most field (so it matches carry/overflow flags)
  // indexed must be the LSB (fixme or get rid of it)
  // shiftcls must occupy the same bits that a real class pointer would
  // bits + RC_ONE is equivalent to extra_rc + 1
  // RC_HALF is the high bit of extra_rc (i.e. half of its range)

  // future expansion:
  // uintptr_t fast_rr : 1;     // no r/r overrides
  // uintptr_t lock : 2;        // lock for atomic property, @synch
  // uintptr_t extraBytes : 1;  // allocated with extra bytes

# if __arm64__
#   define ISA_MASK        0x0000000ffffffff8ULL
#   define ISA_MAGIC_MASK  0x000003f000000001ULL
#   define ISA_MAGIC_VALUE 0x000001a000000001ULL
  struct isa_t {
    uintptr_t indexed           : 1;
    uintptr_t has_assoc         : 1;
    uintptr_t has_cxx_dtor      : 1;
    uintptr_t shiftcls          : 33;                 // MACH_VM_MAX_ADDRESS 0x1000000000
    uintptr_t magic             : 6;
    uintptr_t weakly_referenced : 1;
    uintptr_t deallocating      : 1;
    uintptr_t has_sidetable_rc  : 1;
    uintptr_t extra_rc          : 19;
#       define RC_ONE   (1ULL<<45)
#       define RC_HALF  (1ULL<<18)
  };

  NSLog(@"arm64");
  static void *someKey = &someKey;
  id object = [NSObject new];

  struct isa_t *isa = (__bridge struct isa_t *)object;

  NSLog(@"%d", isa->has_assoc);


  objc_setAssociatedObject(object, someKey, @"Hello World!", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

  NSLog(@"%d", isa->has_assoc);


  NSLog(@"%p", *(void * *)(__bridge void *)object);


# elif __x86_64__
#   define ISA_MASK        0x00007ffffffffff8ULL
#   define ISA_MAGIC_MASK  0x001f800000000001ULL
#   define ISA_MAGIC_VALUE 0x001d800000000001ULL
  struct isa_t {
    uintptr_t indexed           : 1;
    uintptr_t has_assoc         : 1;
    uintptr_t has_cxx_dtor      : 1;
    uintptr_t shiftcls          : 44;                 // MACH_VM_MAX_ADDRESS 0x7fffffe00000
    uintptr_t magic             : 6;
    uintptr_t weakly_referenced : 1;
    uintptr_t deallocating      : 1;
    uintptr_t has_sidetable_rc  : 1;
    uintptr_t extra_rc          : 8;
#       define RC_ONE   (1ULL<<56)
#       define RC_HALF  (1ULL<<7)
  };

  NSLog(@"x86_64");
  static void *someKey = &someKey;
  id object = [NSObject new];

  struct isa_t *isa = (__bridge struct isa_t *)object;

  NSLog(@"%d", isa->has_assoc);


  objc_setAssociatedObject(object, someKey, @"Hello World!", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

  NSLog(@"%d", isa->has_assoc);


  NSLog(@"%p", *(void * *)(__bridge void *)object);
# else
  // Available bits in isa field are architecture-specific.
#   error unknown architecture
# endif


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You tested on the simulator. The article you linked says this:

> The 64-bit iOS simulator currently does not use non-pointer isa. Test your code on a real arm64 device.

You have to test on a device to see a non-pointer `isa`.